# Put variable to line above current line VIm

Tags: vimscript, gvim

I'm writing a function to automate a repetitive task. Copied from a macro so still not elegant while I get it to work.

Basically I want to fold a xml file my way to make visual comparison easier for files that may differ in size by 10,0000 plus lines due to differences in what the xml production program  is querying

Two types of file `M` and `U`. All works as expected except for the put command `:put =foldbegin`.

Function

```
function! FoldXml(mcr)

   echom a:mcr
   if ( a:mcr == 'M' )
     let taglist = ['getContractDetailsResponse', 'contractDetailsResponse', 'contractInfo']
     set wrapscan
   else
     let taglist=['product', 'status', 'company', 'region']
     set wrapscan
   endif
     "Tags to process
 "    let tot=len(taglist) 
     let tot=1
     "Where we start
     let start=0
     "Fold stuff
     let BeginStart='"=== BEGIN '
     let BeginEnd=' ==={{{'
     let EndStart='"=== END '
     let EndEnd=' ===}}}'
     norm! gg
     while start < tot 
       "beginning. Not needed but hey :)
         norm! gg
         "WHat number we up to
         let s1=expand(start)
         "Set up some stuff
         "Begin search
         "let findStart='<'.taglist[expand(start)].'>'
         let findStart='<'.taglist[s1].'>'
         "End search
         let findEnd='<\/'.taglist[s1].'>'
         "Fold stuff
         let foldbegin=BeginStart.taglist[s1].BeginEnd
         let foldend=EndStart.taglist[s1].EndEnd
         "find first match for current value of taglist[start]. Will try a
         "better regex solution later
         call search(findStart)
         "Why need : but norm! gg doesn't ?
         :norm! k
         "paste the beginning fold
         :put =foldbegin
         call search(findEnd)
         :put =foldend
         let start = start + 1
     endwhile
  endfunction
```

The file looks like this

```
<getContractDetailsResponse>   
  <contractDetailsResponse>

....

  </contractDetailsResponse>
</getContractDetailsResponse>

vim:foldmethod=marker:foldclose=all:tw=88:ts=8:shiftwidth=2:noexpandtab
```

How do I get the `:put =foldbegin` to open a line above rather than below as happens with `:put =foldend`?

Comment: `:-1put =foldbegin`
Full command is `:[line]put [x]` where [line] is line number by default is current line `-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To `:put` a line above the current line, add an exclamation point: `:put!`. See

```
:help :put
```

and scroll down a bit.