# How do I access variables in if statements?

Tags: vimscript, gvim

Following on from [Put variable to line above current line VIm](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/put-variable-to-line-above-current-line-vim/4603#4603)

I added some logic to only run if the begin and end tags in the list are present, snippet

```
....
let findStart='<'.taglist[s1].'>'
let findEnd='<'.'\/'.ns.taglist[s1].'>'

let fs=0
let fe=0


while something
  let fs=search(expand(findStart))
  let fe=search(expand(findEnd))
  if ( &fs>0 && &fe>0 )
      call search(findStart,'b')
      "paste the beginning fold
      :-1put =foldbegin
      .....
      :let fs=0
      :let fe=0
  endif 
let something=something +1
endwhile
```

In modeline this `:let fs=0|:call search('<')|echo fs` returns the position of the search. In Vimscript the only way I can use the variable in an if statement is `if ( &fs>0 ... )`.

I can't find anything to explain why the statements work differently so I can make sense of it. Any suggestions of where to look for answers?

Also  `:let fs=0` within the if doesn't reset the variable. Why?

UPDATE: It's something to do with using 2 letter variables but I don't know what the issue is despite googling it.

Comment: You should use scoping for variables. For example `let l:fs = 0` makes `fs` as a local variable for your function and prevent you from interact with global, options etc.

Comment: Variables inside a function are local by default.  You have to use `g:` to access global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help, if you could include the error message in your question.

When using '&variables' you are effectively accessing option values. See the help at `:h expr-option`.

So in your if statement you should **not** use `if &fs` if you want to check a variable and not the option value 'fsync', but using &fe will cause an error, because there exists no option with that (short-)name.

Comment: No error message I could trap but that points me to the right place to look thanks. It explains why &fe was never true.